# Shortcoding with Divs

Tags: php, functions, shortcode

I am trying to turn a custom query into a shortcode but I am having some difficulty. Firstly, I am not sure how to return a custom thumbnail size via `$return_string`...in fact I am not sure how to return most of my styling. here is what I have so far.

I'd like to put this:

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query
            (array('showposts' => 3, 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC'));
            while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();?>
                <div class="recent_post">
                    <div class="recent_title">          
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="recent_img">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('recent_news_size'); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="recent_excerpt">
                        <?php echo excerpt(22); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Into my shortcode here:

```
function recent_posts_function($atts){
   extract(shortcode_atts(array(
      'posts' => 1,
   ), $atts));

   query_posts(array('orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC' , 'showposts' => $posts));
   if (have_posts()) :
      while (have_posts()) : the_post();
         $return_string .= '//put stuff here';
      endwhile;
   endif;

   wp_reset_query();
   return $return_string;
}

function register_shortcodes(){
   add_shortcode('recent-posts', 'recent_posts_function');
}

add_action( 'init', 'register_shortcodes');
```

Do any of you gurus know of a quick and easy way to turn it all into a shortcode?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick: http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Output

Copying verbatim from the documentation:

```
function myShortCode() {
    ob_start();
    ?> <HTML> <here> ... <?PHP
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Basically what happens is that all your HTML will not be output, but rather stored in an "output buffer", and returned by the function.